# Copy without duplicates using generic function

Tags: c++, generics

I'm trying to make a generic function which will copy elements without duplicates from one block to another. Function accepts three pointers/iterators and must work for all types of iterators. Function should return a pointer/iterator that points exactly one place behind the destination block.

p1 and p2 are from the same type. However, p3 doesn't have to be the same type as p1 and p2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
template<typename iter_type1, typename iter_type2>
auto CopyWithoutDuplicate(iter_type1 p1, iter_type1 p2, iter_type2 p3){
    int n=std::distance(p1,p2);
    std::unique_copy(p1,p2,p3);
    p3+=n;
    return p3;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s="abc defabcd ghidef",str;
    std::vector<int>a{1,1,2,2,3,4,3,5},b;
    auto it1=CopyWithoutDuplicate(s.begin(),s.end(),str.begin());
    while(it1!=str.begin())
    {
        std::cout<<*it1;
        it1--;
    }
    std::cout<<endl;
    auto it2=CopyWithoutDuplicate(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin());
    while(it2!=b.begin())
    {
        std::cout<<*it2<<" ";
        it2--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Correct output would be:
>
> abc defghi
>
> 1 2 3 4 5

I tried to use `std::unique_copy` for this, but I don't know where I made mistaked in my code. This doesn't print anything on screen.

Comment: `std::unique_copy`: Copies the elements from the range `[first, last)`, to another range beginning at `d_first` in such a way that **there are no consecutive equal elements**. The correct output of `std::unique_copy` is abc defabcd ghidef 1 2 3 4 3 5 as documented. In other words, it removes closest duplicates.

Comment: `std::unique_copy` doesn't remove all duplicates - it removes consecutive duplicates. It will turn `aabb` into `ab`, but it will leave `abab` unchanged. If you need a function that turns `abab` into `ab`, you'd have to roll your own.

Comment: In addition to all of that, the algorithm for computing the return value, based on `p3` is flawed.

Comment: could you give me some ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Place processed elements in `std::unordered_map`. If a current element is found in the map, skip it, do not copy to `p3`.

Comment: The users of `CopyWithoutDuplicate` also need to make sure that the range to which `p3` points is large enough to store all of the copied items. Currently you are passing empty iterators to the beginning of empty ranges in `main`. That is fundamentally not going to work with the iterator interface.

Comment: @273K is there any way to do this without unordered_map?

Comment: For small value ranges like in the char type you can use an array. Another way is O(N^2). There is no other ways if you are going to keep the original order.

Comment: could you post any code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CopyWithoutDuplicate` can be simplified.

```
auto CopyWithoutDuplicate(iter_type1 p1, iter_type1 p2, iter_type2 p3){
    return std::unique_copy(p1,p2,p3);
}
```

The working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

template<typename iter_type1, typename iter_type2>
iter_type2 CopyWithoutDuplicate(iter_type1 p1, iter_type1 p2, iter_type2 p3){
  std::unordered_set<typename std::iterator_traits<iter_type1>::value_type> m;
  for (; p1 != p2; ++p1) {
    if (m.count(*p1) != 0)
      continue;
    *p3++ = *p1;
    m.insert(*p1);
  }
  return p3;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s="abc defabcd ghidef",str;
    std::vector<int>a{1,1,2,2,3,4,3,5},b;
    CopyWithoutDuplicate(s.begin(),s.end(),std::back_inserter(str));
    for(char c : str)
        std::cout<<c;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    CopyWithoutDuplicate(a.begin(),a.end(),std::back_inserter(b));
    for(int n : b)
        std::cout<<n<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
abc defghi
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: `typename iter_type1::value_type` should be `typename std::iterator_traits<iter_type1>::value_type`; or else it won't work if e.g. `iter_type1` is a plain pointer.

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik, I missed and thus did not consider pointers.

Comment: thank you very much, could you explain me what this means? `<typename std::iterator_traits<iter_type1>::value_type> m;`

Comment: also I cannot compile `main.cpp:23:69: error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token`

Comment: @273K I'm using c++14, could you write me this line of code that supports c++14 `CopyWithoutDuplicate(s.begin(),s.end(),std::back_insert_iterator(str));`

Comment: Why don't attempt to read manuals and learn C++ a bit deeper? [std::back_insert_iterator, See also](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator)

Comment: thanks, I'm student still, so I stick to my lectures mostly

Comment: you could use `using tip=typename std::decay<decltype(*p1)>::type;
  std::set<tip>m;` also